# Modifying sensitivity to multicollinearity in plm function in R

Tags: r, multicollinearity, plm

The plm() function, which is part of the [plm package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=plm), in R drops variables that are near-collinear to avoid singularities. [Stata's xtreg](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/xtxtreg.pdf) does the same, but either uses different thresholds or a different selection mechanism on which variables to drop. Running the same model with the same data thus yields different estimates because different variables are (automatically) dropped.

My question is: is there a way to either (a) change the threshold at which a certain near-collinear variable is dropped, or (b) force manually to keep certain variables no matter what?

Comment: `plm` is not part of `R`: it's an add-on package.  Your best bet is to read the source code.  If you would like to get comparable estimates, why not manually drop the same variables in `R` that Stata has dropped (or *vice versa*)?

Comment: I'm aware that plm is not a core function of R. As for the manually dropping of variables: R (or plm, for that matter) drops _more_ variables than Stata, which makes the replication of Stata results impossible unless plm's sensitivity for dropping near-collinear variables is lowered.

Comment: I don't know much about plm() but I don't see anything in either the ?plm helpfile or the package vignette https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/vignettes/plm.pdf that says it drops variables in this situation (which sounds like a bad idea to me, but that's an aside).  Are you sure it does this?  BTW I presume the downvote was because this was a "how do I do X with software Y" question - an interesting statistical version would be what would be a sensible way to deal with this collinearity problem with panel data in particular.

Comment: Should this not be closed as off-topic? I agree there is an underlying statistical question, but this seems to be about how to do something in a particular package.

Comment: @Peter That's a legitimate question.  These issues look like they require statistical reasoning to resolve, although some knowledge of the software platforms might be needed, too.  Durden, of course you're aware `plm` is non-core: after all, you had to invoke  a `library` or `require` function to access it.  However, it would behoove you to explicitly inform readers interested in addressing your problem concerning what this software really is and where information about it can be found.  Misleadingly suggesting it's part of base `R` is going to waste their time.

Comment: Valid point, I"ll fix my post.